# Access generated 'R' or 'R.drawable` object in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

#### What I’m trying to do:

On our project we reference UI libraries from 3rd parties (delivered via maven/aar) and one of those libraries has a bunch of vector drawables we should use.

It’s a pain to do and very error prone to keep referencing those icons with the fully qualified package like `com.client1.ui.compose.R.drawables.my_icon`, so I wanted to add either `R` or `R.drawables` to another object for easier reference, we already got an object for that in code and wanted to add it there, something like this:

```kotlin
object Client1Stuff {
   val foo : Foo = Client1.foo // some existing client specific foo
   val bar : Bar = Client1.bar // some other existing client specific bar

   // I wanted to add the icons here
   val icons = com.client1.ui.compose.R.drawables // or maybe just the 'R'
}
```

Imagine how nicer and less error prone would be to write `Client1Stuff.icons.my_icon`

#### What error I get:

But unfortunately I get this error:

> Classifier ‘drawable’ does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here.

#### Also tried:

The same error if I try to reference `R` and also if trying to reference inside a normal function, for example:

```kotlin
fun something() {
  // this works all good
  val icon: Int = com.client1.ui.compose.R.drawables.my_icon 

  // this give error
  // Classifier ‘drawable’ does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
  val drawables = com.client1.ui.compose.R.drawables

  // this also give error
  // Classifier ‘R’ does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
  val resources = com.client1.ui.compose.R
}
```

I’m pretty sure in the past we could reference those objects and could even see their code in the builder/generated folder with all the integers there.

#### Question:

Maybe there's some Gradle plugin configuration I could add for the resources to be pre-compiled and access that?
Anyone can help with it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried several approaches with flags passing to the `gradle.properties` but non allowed me to reference the class as it was possible before.

So the second best solution was to make a type alias instead:

```kotlin
internal typealias Client1Icons = com.client1.ui.compose.R.drawables
object Client1Stuff {
   val foo : Foo = Client1.foo
   val bar : Bar = Client1.bar
}
```

and it becomes easy to use:

```kotlin
Image(
  painter = painterResource(id = Client1Icons.my_icon),
  contentDescription = "icon"
)
```

Comment: you tried `android.nonTransitiveRClass=false` and `android.nonFinalResIds=false` on gradle.properties right?